# Error with Google Play Services 5.0.77

Tags: android, admob

I moved from Google Play Services 4.3.23 to 5.0.77 and I get an error in XML file for AdMob ads:

```
        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER" />
```

Error:

```
    java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 57 in method com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.onMeasure(II)V at offset 20
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2404)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2714)
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1674)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:310)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:100)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.ProjectCallback.loadView(ProjectCallback.java:165)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:135)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:727)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:373)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:399)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:336)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:332)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$3.compute(RenderService.java:548)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$3.compute(RenderService.java:537)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:929)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:537)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.render(RenderService.java:609)
    at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$7.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:497)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:297)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

When I start the app, it crashes.

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #125: Error inflating class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
```

I tried 4.4.52 and it works fine.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

What is the difference between Google Play Services 4.3.23, 4.4.52 and 5.0.77? Does new versions display better ads or something like that?

Should I update my apps then to version 4.4.52 and publish it, or it's not necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using Android Studio, you can fix this error the following way (assuming Windows):

1. Open your install directory of Android Studio, then go to the /bin subfolder
2. Open studio64.exe.vmoptions
3. Add the following line at the bottom of the file:

> -XX:-UseSplitVerifier

4. Close and re-launch Android Studio.

Worked for me!